# Cannot use SQLite WAL mode

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using c# with NHibernate on SQLite.
System.Data.SQLite version 1.0.88
SQLite version 3.7.17

I've recently found out about SQLite [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) and it looks like just what I need.
The problem is that I can't seem to get it to work.

The documentation simply states:

> To convert to WAL mode, use the following pragma:
>
> PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
>
> The journal_mode pragma returns a string which is
> the new journal mode. On success, the pragma will return the string
> "wal". If the conversion to WAL could not be completed (for example,
> if the VFS does not support the necessary shared-memory primitives)
> then the journaling mode will be unchanged and the string returned
> from the primitive will be the prior journaling mode (for example
> "delete").

I've tried this both within code:

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;");
object result = query.UniqueResult();
```

and within the [SQLiteman](http://sqliteman.com/) management application.

In each case, I get a return value of 'delete'. i.e. The database has failed to enter WAL mode.
Trouble is, I have no idea why.. The only possibility I can see in the documentation is your file system not supporting shared-memory primatives, but I'm on Win 7 so that's not an issue.

Any ideas how I can enable WAL mode or figure out why it's not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try set the pragma on your connection builder.

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
connBuilder.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Wal;
```

Check out this:
[System.data.sqlite - Activating WAL Journal Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685897/system-data-sqlite-activating-wal-journal-mode/10531863#10531863)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.
It seems that the journal mode needs to be set when the connection is first created. (I haven't found any documentation stating that for definite but it's the only way I can get it to work)

I now specify the journal mode when creating the connection string:

```
SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = dbFile;
connectionStringBuilder.JournalMode = SQLiteJournalModeEnum.Wal;
```

My Fluent NHbiernate config then uses this:

```
SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionStringBuilder.ToString())
```

Comment: Yep, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite doesnt actually change the journaling mode until a write (or read?) has been issued to the database. Im not familiar with the C# interface, but I've seen it with the Objective C interface.